How to How to make Qwen-7B-Chat-Int4 compatible with LLMChainExtractor.from_llm()?
The following is an example code snippet from the LangChain official website that demonstrates adding context compression using LLMChainExtractor:
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.retrievers import ContextualCompressionRetriever
from langchain.retrievers.document_compressors import LLMChainExtractor

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
compressor = LLMChainExtractor.from_llm(llm)
compression_retriever = ContextualCompressionRetriever(base_compressor=compressor, base_retriever=retriever)

compressed_docs = compression_retriever.get_relevant_documents("What did the president say about Ketanji Jackson Brown")
pretty_print_docs(compressed_docs)

However, in my project, I am not using OPENAI but instead using Qwen-7B-Chat-Int4 as the llm. An error occurs when attempting this. How can I modify the code to ensure that Qwen-7B-Chat-Int4 is compatible with LLMChainExtractor.from_llm()?
In my project files, the error-prone code is as follows.
compressor = LLMChainExtractor.from_llm(llm)

The displayed error message is as follows.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/yht/LZX/langchain-chat-with-your-data/chatbot.py", line 120, in \<module\>
compressor = LLMChainExtractor.from_llm(llm)
File "/home/yht/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/retrievers/document_compressors/chain_extract.py", line 108, in from_llm
llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=\_prompt, \*\*(llm_chain_kwargs or {}))
File "/home/yht/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_core/load/serializable.py", line 97, in __init__
super().__init__(\*\*kwargs)
File "pydantic/main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for LLMChain
llm
instance of Runnable expected (type=type_error.arbitrary_type; expected_arbitrary_type=Runnable)
llm
instance of Runnable expected (type=type_error.arbitrary_type; expected_arbitrary_type=Runnable)

I haven't found any online information regarding how to make Qwen-7B-Chat-Int4 compatible with LLMChainExtractor.from_llm().
